# Angular 7 Http Client and Asp Core - Cors error

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, request, httpclient, angular7

I'm stuck with an error in Angular 7. I'm doing a post request to Asp Core API passing an object, and that API response an `Ok()` with another object. My code is like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserRegistration(ViewModel viewModel){
    //Ignored code
    return Ok(someObject);
}
```

That action is working (apparently) great, it accepts the request, resolves any necessary decision and returns the object exactly as I need.
 Now lets to Angular app, where I have a method in `service.ts` which call the api, and another one in `component.ts` which consumes that first method. They are like that:

```
//Service
userRegistration(model): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.post(url, model, httpOptions);
}

//Component
saveUser(model){
   this.myService.userRegistration(model).subscribe(
      data => {
         //do something
      },
      error => {
         //show message
      }
   );
}
```

The point here is that Angular has success on calling Asp Core API which saves properly the data in database, returns the correct object, and then Angular gets error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'endpoint' from origin 'origin' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "URL", ok: false, …}

Why is it saying CORS error if API accepts the request and responses it properly? How can I solve that?

Comment: I already answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308130/cross-origin-request-blocked-on-http-post-request/56309521#56309521)

Comment: Thanks @TonyNgo. I have already configured cors, but it still failing

Comment: Do you use correct protocol of url to web api in angular, http or https? Could you show your CORS configuration in startup? Try to use `WithOrigins` instead of `AllowAnyOrigin`.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#set-the-allowed-origins

Comment: @XingZou You can't imagine how stupid was my question. Shamefully it was just a problem with browser cache. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add CORS in **startup.cs** in backend

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
  {
    services.AddMvc();
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {
      options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowMyOrigin"));
    });
  }
```

For more details, follow this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/cors-in-net-core-net-core-security-part-vi)

Comment: Thanks! I've already configured cors in Startup.cs, but error persists.